# Laravel Validation: the column of the input must be the same as logined user's email

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I wanted to make sure that the coupon code can only be used by certain user which i referred as beneficiary in my coupons table ([Coupons table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95aEC.png)). Hence I used the laravel validation method whereby the beneficiary must be the same as the logined user or could be referred as `auth()->user()->email` but I am not sure how do I write it in my CouponsController.php.

The coupon section in my checkout.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ route('coupon.store') }}" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="coupon_code" id="coupon_code">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-plain">Apply</button>
</form>
```

CouponsController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $coupon = Coupon::where('code', $request->coupon_code)->first();

    if (!$coupon) {
        return redirect()->route('checkout.index')->withErrors('Invalid coupon code. Please try again.');
    }

    session()->put('coupon', [
        'name' => $coupon->code,
        'discount' => $coupon->discount(Cart::subtotal()),
        'discountrate' => $coupon->showdiscount(),
        'beneficiary' => $coupon->beneficiary,
    ]);

    $this->validate($request, [ 'beneficiary' => 'same:users,email']);

    return redirect()->route('checkout.index')->with('success_message', 'Coupon has been applied!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $userEmail = Auth::user()->email; //logged in user email
    $coupon = Coupon::where('code', $request->coupon_code)->where('beneficiary',$userEmail)->first();

    if (!$coupon) {
        return redirect()->route('checkout.index')->withErrors('Invalid coupon code. Please try again.');
    }

    session()->put('coupon', [
        'name' => $coupon->code,
        'discount' => $coupon->discount(Cart::subtotal()),
        'discountrate' => $coupon->showdiscount(),
        'beneficiary' => $coupon->beneficiary,
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('checkout.index')->with('success_message', 'Coupon has been applied!');
}
```

Comment: After following the above code I now get the error of "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::email()"

Comment: ok i got it, just change from $userEmail = Auth::user()->email(); to $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;